# Matlab figure visualization

Tags: matlab, plot, division, figure, subplot

In Matlab, I would like to visualize the test results in a figure with several charts and text. The figure is divided into rows and colums: 3 rows and 5 colums. For better understanding, here a screenshot of the figure with a orange grid which shows the subplot division:

[image]

Now I have several questions:

A) How can I include text into a specific section within the figure? i.e. test settings into subplot(6 and 11) and test results into subplot (7, 8, 9, 10).

B) Is it possible to "draw" separator lines between the subplots? i.e. to separate the test settings from the test result subplots for a better visualization.

C) Is it possible to set a title over several subplots such as "input data" and "output data"?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come this problem many times and haven't yet figured out a decent way to solve it. However what you can do is:

A) Include a Label (help label) in the subplot you want. Alternatively use a "edit locked" edit text field.

B) Yes in a way. Check out panels. Create a subplot, then inside a panel that fills the plot area. with the panel as parent create a figure (or label as in A) )

C) Thats a tricky one and I would use panels again, but I am not sure if that works.

These things are always a pain to do in Matlab itself. I usually ended up exporting my figures, writing a small HTML generator that places the images in divs and a decent CSS to make it look nice. It is way easier to do so if it is only for representing data. If you want it to be interactive you have to do it inside the UI.

Hope that helps
Benjamin

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I was not able to do it like you have written in your answer. Could you please give me an example or a link where I can find more information? I don't understand how to include a label into a subplot (which is a chart automatically)...

Comment: Oh yes you are right. Thing is, I am currently travelling and don't have Matlab with me to send you some code that will work. However I have a link for a toolbox that might be interesting as it allows you to configure complex GUI layouts: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox